# Run function in time

Tags: php

I want block user ip if run this function more than 5 times, and this limit only be for 15 minutes, is it possible? newbie to `php` and no idea how should start or using what? no matter how to block user ip.. i just want to know how can i set limit in certain time.

if executed more than 5 , block for 15 minutes
after 15 minutes user can execute, but if again more than 5 times, block it again.

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_GET['login'])){
// some code
function sendSMS(){
// do something 
}
}
```

Need logic and what `php` function should use?

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want some people to write you the code?
You should write it yourself and if you need help with a specific task you can ask here. If you want to put your programm in the internet you should be more experienced in php.